# CORS redirect in Cordova

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova, cors

I have a Cordova/Phonegap application trying to get some files with AJAX. I get the following error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=.... Redirect from 'https://docs.google.com/uc?export=open&id=...' to 'https://doc-xx-xx-docs.googleusercontent.com/docs/...?e=open' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 
>   'null' is therefore not allowed access.

I tried adding the following to `config.xml`

```
<access origin="*" />
<allow-navigation href="*" />
<allow-navigation href="http://*/*" />
<allow-navigation href="https://*/*" />
```

and also added to `index.html`

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: 'unsafe-eval' 'unsafe-inline' http: https:">
```

I'm accessing the application in the browser using `cordova serve`.

I still get the same error. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't​ have control over the endpoint you may well need to setup your own API to do this.

For example if you create an endpoint in php you could include the line:

```
 header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Then your end point can forward the request to the Google endpoint which will pass the response to your API and that can pass your app the response.

I believe the Google endpoint will accept a request from other servers but not if the origin is null.

In effect you need to make sure your request is coming from a http:// and not a file:// URL.

Comment: Endpoint in php? I said that this is a Cordova application and I cannot install a php proxy.

Comment: I understand it's a Cordova app. However  a XMLHttpRequest from Cordova will be sent with the header of origin null. Google's endpoint that you are requesting the file from doesn't accept a null origin so I'm thinking you may need your own API on your own server as a proxy for sending the request.

Comment: Added a little bit to my answer to hopefully clear up my point.

Answer (score 0):

Well,  these 're the settings for browser platform and android platform you can apply.

config.xml

```
<allow-navigation href="*://doc.google.com/*" />

...

<platform name="android">
     ...
     <resource-file src="resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
</platform>
```

network_security_config.xml

```
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomain="true">doc.google.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```